# Pesquisa entre Datas Access para Período de Ferias

Tags: microsoft-access

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com dificuldade em inserir uma pesquisa no MS Access para pontuar se um colaborador está em período de férias, estou inserindo a seguinte fórmula:

```
Status_: SeImed([Data_] Entre [DT INI GOZO_] E [DT FIN GOZO_];"Ferias""Ativo")
```

Porém o resultado está pulando da `Data Início` e indo para `Data Fim`, entre as datas está dando como se o colaborador estivesse `Ativo`, porém o mesmo está de `Férias`.